# Autodiff package with extended symmetric matrix/tensor support

Tags: linear-algebra, autodiff

Does at the current point in time exist any linear algebra package that supports both automatic differentiation and symmetric matrices?

It is often important that during a sequence of computations some matrix stays symmetric. One possible solution is to apply the projection onto the symmetric part `A <- (A + transpose(A))/2` after each computation. For obvious reasons this is sub-optimal at best, and prohibitively slow in the worst case.

What I am looking for is a linear algebra package with **guarantees** that certain operations involving symmetric matrices yield symmetric matrices. For instance:

`A + B`, `AB+BA`, `A^n`, `A'`, `c*A`, `VAV'`,`VV'`, `V'V` `A^-1`, `exp(A)`, `A∘B`, `A ⊗ B`,

Should all be symmetric again, given `A`, `B` symmetric, `V` arbitrary, `c` scalar.

Comment: The product of symmetric matrices A,B will only be symmetric if A and B commute

Comment: @dmuir fixed. feel free to edit the post if you spot a mistake like this